# Error on running scout:import command. Internal error: panic

Tags: laravel, laravel-scout, meilisearch

I am using laravel scout with meilisearch driver.

The problem is:

When I run the command `php artisan scout:import "App\Models\Article"` the below error is shown:
I am using laravel 8.

```
MeiliSearch\Exceptions\ApiException 

 Internal error: panic

at vendor/meilisearch/meilisearch-php/src/Http/Client.php:197
    193▕     private function parseResponse(ResponseInterface $response)
    194▕     {
    195▕         if ($response->getStatusCode() >= 300) {
    196▕             $body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true) ?? $response->getReasonPhrase();
  ➜ 197▕             throw new ApiException($response, $body);
    198▕         }
    199▕ 
    200▕         return json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    201▕     }

      +26 vendor frames 
  27  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

the content of composer.json is like this:

```
"require": {
        "laravel/scout": "^9.2",
        "meilisearch/meilisearch-php": "^0.18.3"

 },
```

`Article` model:

```
class Article extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, Searchable;

    protected $table = 'article';
    public function searchableAs()
    {
        return 'body';
    }
    public function toSearchableArray(){
        return $this->only(['title' , 'body']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.

I must use this command for running meilisearch:

`./meilisearch --db-path ./meilifiles --http-addr '127.0.0.1:7700' --master-key="hS3w2KEJCsLdpdaSZIZg"`

Instead of this command:

`./meilisearch --master-key="hS3w2KEJCsLdpdaSZIZg"`